# Backendless - save objects in specific tables without having the class for Java object to persist

Tags: android, backendless

I want to create multiple tables and I want to be able to add records in them without having the Java object classes for each of them. In Parse I could make

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

How I can do something similar with Backendless ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Backendless (asyncCallback is an instance of com.backendless.async.callback.AsyncCallback):

```
HashMap gameScore = new HashMap();
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
Backendless.Data.of( "GameScore" ).save( gameScore, asyncCallback );
```